# nuget update command with packages.<projectName>.config

Tags: nuget, nuget-update

It seems that **nuget update** command does not support *packages.projectName.config* format of packages.config' file name.

```
nuget update packages.<project>.config
```

returns: *No packages.config, project or solution file specified.*

But it works for **nuget restore** command.

Are there methods to make update work without renaming of config file?

Comment: Which NuGet version do you use? You could also have a look at the source code.

Comment: Version: 3.5.0.1938

Quick research in the source code shows that UpdateCommand and RestoreCommands use different logic for handling the name. 

But I thought that may be there are some workarounds.